# Bad encoding when renaming html file to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, character-encoding

I had a file index.html with accents, and everything went fine.
Since I changed it for index.php, I see encoding problems. So I replaced accent with HTML entities in index.php and it displays well.
My last problem now is I have a form where inputs have custom placeholders fill in javascript, containing accents. Even with html entities these placeholders are displayed with encoding problem. How can I resolve this ?
In my index.php I have :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

And in firebug I have :

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Try using `<meta charset="utf-8"> `.

Comment: Same problem Jerodev

Answer (score 1):

When you're saving your file in text editor choose "Save As" usually you can choose encoding, for example in **windows NotePad**... 
in **Sublime** you can choose "Save with encoding"
in **PSPAD** you have to click on Format and choose encoding before saving... 
**Notepad++** i found this didn't checked it "In Notepad++ 5.9 there is an option in Settings -> Preferences -> New Document/Default Directory to automatically convert ANSI files to UTF-8 without BOM on open"

Comment: I'm using Netbeans and my whole project in in UTF-8, I will try to see this file's encoding